# SQL - Select unique instances of combined values in (C 1 & C 2) with different values in C 3

Tags: sql, select

Select the items with unique instances of combined values in (C 1 & C 2) with different values in C 3. In the information below I am looking to SELECT Item 1 from R2 and/or Item 1 from R3.

```
          C 1    C 2            C 3
    R1  Item 1   Thing 1      Stuff 1
    R2  Item 1   Thing 2      Stuff 2
    R3  Item 1   Thing 2      Stuff 1
    R4  Item 2   Thing 3      Stuff 1
```

Comment: First figure out your database system don't tag MySQL, SQL-server and PostgreSQL in one question. i've changed the question to be SQL only related for this reason.

Comment: Are you confused about rows and columns, because the question is really hard to understand.

Comment: There are some solutions here for you.  Since I see that you're new, first - Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Also, don't forget to 'Accept' the answer that works for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
            Table1.*
        FROM Table1  INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT
            C1 , C2 ,COUNT(DISTINCT C3) AS dCount 

        FROM Table1          
        GROUP BY C1 , C2
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C3) > 1 
        ) Ct ON Table1.C1 = ct.C1 AND  Table1.C2 = ct.C2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to clean up the data first.  Since 'Item 1' will never equal 'Thing 1', I think you mean:

```
      Item     Thing      Stuff 
R1    1        1          1
R2    1        2          2
R3    1        2          1
R4    2        3          1
```

If I'm right about that part, then this query will get the distinct rows (since you mentioned "unique") where Item and Thing are equal (hope that's what you meant by "combined values") and Stuff is something different - in other words, "combined values in (C 1 & C 2) with different values in C 3".

```
select distinct *
    from your_table
    where Item = Thing and Stuff <> Item
```

or (same thing using C1, C2, and C3)

```
select distinct *
    from your_table
    where C1 = C2 and C3 <> C1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the combinations, I think you want:

```
select c1, c2
from t
group by c1, c2
having min(c3) <> max(c3);
```

Admittedly, this interprets your question liberally interpreting "row" as "column".